# Java About Jsession_id Appending in Browser

Tags: java, cookies, jboss

I am new to  java and using `jboss 4.x server`,  **My problem** is  `jsession_id` is appending on the browser when the `cookies` are disabled but I want to remove `jsession-id` appended in the `url`.

I am using `jboss 4.x` version can we enable `cookies` at code level so that `jsession_id` would be removed from the `url` or we have any filters to filter it.

Comment: you can not enable cookie at code level

Comment: Appending Jsession_id to the url is security issue so how can i resolve it ,please can  u suggest me any other way

Comment: store jsession_id in session or cookie.